# Image stretches on IOS devices and Safari, but totally fine on Chrome

Tags: html, css, ios, web, bootstrap-4

I’m working on a website genesisai.bio that works perfectly on Chrome, but an image stretches on safari and IOS devices. How can I fix that? 
I tried playing around with setting height: auto on relevant media spots and also tried working with flex. As I'm new to this, I can't seem to find the work around. I'd appreciate any help!

EDIT:

```html
<section class="banner-area relative" id="home">
                <div class="container" >
                        <div class="row fullscreen align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <div class="banner-content col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                                <h1 class="text-uppercase">
                                    Sharing data your way <br>
                                </h1>
                                <p>
                                    ABCDEEFF
                                </p>
                                <button class="primary-btn2 mt-20 text-uppercase " onclick="window.location.href = 'survey.html';"> Get Started <span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-self-center img-right">
                                <img class="f-img img-fluid" src="img/back.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

```
::-moz-selection {
  /* Code for Firefox */
  background-color: #2482ff;
  color: #fff;
}

::selection {
  background-color: #2482ff;
  color: #fff;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  color: #777777;
  font-weight: 300;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: #777777;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: #777777;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #777777;
  font-weight: 300;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: #777777;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  color: #777777;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.625em;
  position: relative;
}

ol, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

select {
  display: block;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
}

a, a:focus, a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

.btn.active.focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn.focus:active,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.transition {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.section-full {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.section-half {
  padding: 75px 0;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.inline-flex {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -moz-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.flex-grow {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-left {
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-middle {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-right {
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -moz-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-top {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
  -moz-align-self: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-item-align: start;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.flex-center {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-bottom {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  -moz-align-self: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.space-between {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.space-around {
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -moz-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-column {
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-cell {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.display-table {
  display: table;
}

.light {
  color: #fff;
}

.dark {
  color: #000;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.container.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .no-flex-xs {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.row.no-margin {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.sample-text-area {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 100px 0 70px 0;
}

.text-heading {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

b, i, sup, sub, u, del {
  color: #fcd2ff;
}

.button-area {
  background: #fff;
}

.button-area .border-top-generic {
  padding: 70px 15px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #eee;
}

.button-group-area .genric-btn {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.button-group-area .genric-btn:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.genric-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.genric-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.genric-btn.e-large {
  padding: 0 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.genric-btn.large {
  line-height: 45px;
}

.genric-btn.medium {
  line-height: 30px;
}

.genric-btn.small {
  line-height: 25px;
}

.genric-btn.radius {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.genric-btn.circle {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.genric-btn.arrow {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.genric-btn.arrow span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.genric-btn.default {
  color: #222222;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.default:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f9f9ff;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.default-border {
  border: 1px solid #f9f9ff;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.default-border:hover {
  color: #222222;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.primary {
  color: #fff;
  background: #fcd2ff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.primary:hover {
  color: #fcd2ff;
  border: 1px solid #fcd2ff;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.primary-border {
  color: #fcd2ff;
  border: 1px solid #fcd2ff;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.primary-border:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #fcd2ff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.success {
  color: #fff;
  background: #4cd3e3;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.success:hover {
  color: #4cd3e3;
  border: 1px solid #4cd3e3;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.success-border {
  color: #4cd3e3;
  border: 1px solid #4cd3e3;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.success-border:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #4cd3e3;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.info {
  color: #fff;
  background: #38a4ff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.info:hover {
  color: #38a4ff;
  border: 1px solid #38a4ff;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.info-border {
  color: #38a4ff;
  border: 1px solid #38a4ff;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.info-border:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #38a4ff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.warning {
  color: #fff;
  background: #f4e700;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.warning:hover {
  color: #f4e700;
  border: 1px solid #f4e700;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.warning-border {
  color: #f4e700;
  border: 1px solid #f4e700;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.warning-border:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #f4e700;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.danger {
  color: #fff;
  background: #f44a40;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.danger:hover {
  color: #f44a40;
  border: 1px solid #f44a40;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.danger-border {
  color: #f44a40;
  border: 1px solid #f44a40;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.danger-border:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #f44a40;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.link {
  color: #222222;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.link:hover {
  color: #222222;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9ff;
  background: #fff;
}

.genric-btn.link-border {
  color: #222222;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9ff;
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.genric-btn.link-border:hover {
  color: #222222;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.genric-btn.disable {
  color: #222222, 0.3;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.generic-blockquote {
  padding: 30px 50px 30px 30px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  border-left: 2px solid #fcd2ff;
}

.single-gallery-image {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  height: 200px;
}

.list-style {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

.unordered-list li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 1.82em !important;
}

.unordered-list li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 3px solid #fcd2ff;
  background: #fff;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ordered-list {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.ordered-list li {
  list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
  color: #fcd2ff;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.82em !important;
}

.ordered-list li span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777777;
}

.ordered-list-alpha li {
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  color: #fcd2ff;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.82em !important;
}

.ordered-list-alpha li span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777777;
}

.ordered-list-roman li {
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
  color: #fcd2ff;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.82em !important;
}

.ordered-list-roman li span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777777;
}

.single-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.single-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.input-group-icon {
  position: relative;
}

.input-group-icon .icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.input-group-icon .icon i {
  color: #797979;
}

.input-group-icon .single-input {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.single-textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: none;
}

.single-input-primary:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #fcd2ff;
}

.single-input-accent {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.single-input-accent:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #eb6b55;
}

.single-input-secondary {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.single-input-secondary:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #f09359;
}

.default-switch {
  width: 35px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 8.5px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.default-switch input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.default-switch input + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fcd2ff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.default-switch input:checked + label {
  left: 19px;
}

.primary-switch {
  width: 35px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 8.5px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.primary-switch input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.primary-switch input + label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.primary-switch input + label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 8.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.primary-switch input + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.primary-switch input:checked + label:after {
  left: 19px;
}

.primary-switch input:checked + label:before {
  background: #fcd2ff;
}

.confirm-switch {
  width: 35px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 8.5px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.confirm-switch input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.confirm-switch input + label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.confirm-switch input + label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 8.5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.confirm-switch input + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.confirm-switch input:checked + label:after {
  left: 19px;
}

.confirm-switch input:checked + label:before {
  background: #4cd3e3;
}

.primary-checkbox {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.primary-checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.primary-checkbox input + label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.primary-checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: url(../img/elements/primary-check.png) no-repeat center center/cover;
  border: none;
}

.confirm-checkbox {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.confirm-checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.confirm-checkbox input + label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.confirm-checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: url(../img/elements/success-check.png) no-repeat center center/cover;
  border: none;
}

.disabled-checkbox {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.default-select {
  height: 40px;
}

.default-select .nice-select {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.default-select .nice-select .list {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0px;
}

.default-select .nice-select .list .option {
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  line-height: 28px;
  min-height: 28px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.default-select .nice-select .list .option.selected {
  color: #fcd2ff;
  background: transparent;
}

.default-select .nice-select .list .option:hover {
  color: #fcd2ff;
  background: transparent;
}

.default-select .current {
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.default-select .nice-select::after {
  right: 20px;
}

.form-select {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-select .nice-select {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-select .nice-select .list {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0px;
}

.form-select .nice-select .list .option {
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  line-height: 28px;
  min-height: 28px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.form-select .nice-select .list .option.selected {
  color: #fcd2ff;
  background: transparent;
}

.form-select .nice-select .list .option:hover {
  color: #fcd2ff;
  background: transparent;
}

.form-select .current {
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.form-select .nice-select::after {
  right: 20px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

.default-header {
  padding: 0px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.menu-bar {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-bar span {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.main-menubar {
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  margin-right: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  nav {
    margin-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 50px;
    top: 47px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
  }
  nav a {
    color: #2482ff !important;
  }
  nav a:hover {
    color: #2482ff;
  }
}

nav.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
}

nav a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  nav a {
    margin: 5px 25px;
  }
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #2482ff;
}

.section-gap {
  padding: 120px 0;
}

.section-title {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.section-title h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.section-title p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .section-title p br {
    display: none;
  }
}

.lnr {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.p1-gradient-bg, .primary-btn, .primary-btn:after, .primary-btn2:after, .single-con .content .content-overlay, .footer-social a:hover, .single-footer-widget .bb-btn {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #2380ff 0%, #52fdd9 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #2380ff 0%, #52fdd9 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, #2380ff 0%, #52fdd9 100%);
}

.p2-gradient-bg {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #f40f68 0%, #f86e3d 55%, #fbcd11 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #f40f68 0%, #f86e3d 55%, #fbcd11 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, #f40f68 0%, #f86e3d 55%, #fbcd11 100%);
  opacity: .5;
}

.p1-gradient-color, .banner-content h1, .single-fact h2, .single-footer-widget h3 {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #2380ff 0%, #52fdd9 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #2380ff 0%, #52fdd9 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, #2380ff 0%, #52fdd9 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.primary-btn {
  line-height: 42px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.primary-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.primary-btn span {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-60%);
  right: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.primary-btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.primary-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.primary-btn:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  right: 20px;
}

.primary-btn2 {
  line-height: 42px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #222222;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.primary-btn2:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.primary-btn2 span {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-60%);
  right: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.primary-btn2:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.primary-btn2:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.primary-btn2:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  right: 20px;
}

.no-icon {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.default-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  box-shadow: -21.213px 21.213px 30px 0px rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.3);
}

.sticky-wrapper {
  height: 48px !important;
}

.banner-area {
  background-color: #f9f9ff;
}

.banner-area .fullscreen {
  height: 700px !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .banner-area .fullscreen {
    height: 700px !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .banner-content {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.banner-content h1 {
  font-size: 58px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .banner-content h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .banner-content h1 br {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .banner-content h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
  .banner-content h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}

.banner-content p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 730px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .banner-content p br {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .img-right img {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .img-right img {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.single-feature .icon {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.single-feature .icon .lnr {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.single-feature h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.about-area {
  background-color: #222;
}

.about-right {
  padding-right: 20%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  .about-right {
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .about-right {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
}

.about-right h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 988px) {
  .about-right h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .about-right h1 br {
    display: none;
  }
}

.about-right .form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #656463;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.about-right input, .about-right textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #656463;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.about-right .option {
  color: #222;
}

.about-right .nice-select span {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.about-right textarea {
  height: 150px;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 988px) {
  .about-right textarea {
    height: 70px;
  }
}

.about-right .list {
  width: 100%;
}

.about-right .payment-method {
  color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.consultans-area {
  background-color: #f9f9ff;
}

.consultans-area .header-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.consultans-area .header-text h1 {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.single-con .single-con .title {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.single-con .content {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.single-con .content .content-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .single-con .content .content-overlay {
    left: 65px;
    width: 67%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
  .single-con .content .content-overlay {
    left: 62px;
    width: 68%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 413px) {
  .single-con .content .content-overlay {
    left: 12px;
    width: 92%;
  }
}

.single-con .content:hover .content-overlay {
  opacity: .8;
}

.single-con .content-details {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.single-con .content-details h4 {
  color: #fff;
}

.single-con .content-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.single-con .content:hover .content-details {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.single-con .content-details p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.single-con .fadeIn-bottom {
  top: 80%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .single-con {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your code? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example][https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]

Comment: Hi Philip Eagles, please see my edit above! I don't know what may be of use and what isn't so I posted as much as I could! It's from a bootstrap template, if that helps

Comment: Please remove bootstrap CSS and left only your HTML, if you have your own custom CSS please attach it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove **d-flex** from this code

```
<div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-self-center img-right">
  <img class="f-img img-fluid" src="img/back.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: It did! Could you explain why that was a problem? Thank You once again - I had spent almost half the night trying to fix this :)

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary classes. d-flex is a display flex rule, but align-self-center class is referring to align-self CSS rule and this rule applies for flex child, not a parent. Img becomes a child of flex parent and since does not have width and height tries to expand. And for row div, you do not need align-items-center justify-content-center because the parent does not have d-flex. Please read about flexbox in this wonderful article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

FIX for stretched images on iOS is to add the below class

```
.ios-strech-fix
{
      height: intrinsic;
}
```

The height will scale to the correct aspect ratio of the image. Not stretching the image but scaling the height at the same ratio of the width.

Hope this helps someone, we have had to implement this on all our websites.

Comment: Where did you get `instrinsic` from? Doesn't seem like it's a supported value for `height`